# The following code does not return true

Tags: c#

My code is as follows

```
   int a = 2;
   int b = 2;

   object _aobject = a;
   object _bobject = b;

   Debug.Assert(_aobject == _bobject , "");
```

Why does it returns false ??

Comment: FYI, same code in Java is going to return `true` because Java has `Integer` pool

Comment: @zvdh +1 That is interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `_aobject == _bobject` checks for  reference hence returns false.

Whereas `_aobject.Equals(_bobject )` checks for value ,it will return true

Answer (score 2):

This is because the references of those 2 objects are different. When you compare 2 objects of type `Object` using `==`, you're comparing their references.

You need to use `Equals ()` method to check if objects hold the same value.

Note that for objects of type `string` you can use both types of comparison to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Equals` instead of `==`.

```
_aobject.Equals(_bobject)
```

Answer (score 0):

just try _aobject.Equals(_bobject ) checks for value ,it will return true